# Repository specific special / dot files in Mercurial

Tags: configuration, mercurial, hgignore

What are the most important special / dot files when using a hg repo ?

Like configuration files and similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of files that a Mercurial repo will use for configuration or keep track of state, but here are the ones that have the best chance to come in handy:

`.hg/last-message.txt`  -- used by `hg commit` to store backup of the commit message in case the commit fails.
Example:

```
My commit message!
```

`.hg/localtags` --  define local tags which are not shared among repositories.
Example:

```
8a7b128ab80b58fc2e63258c9e2bf1f58a5be7c2 myfirsttag
08ff3a0b2e5af9a74becbfdf3e92d6e9a2d0c960 secondtag
6535d105ea795a38808481b160314f9857736c53 thirdtag
```

`.hgignore`  -- regular  expressions that describe file names that should be ignored by hg.
Example:

```
syntax: glob

*.elc
*.orig
*.rej
*~
*.mergebackup
*.o
*.so
*.dll
*.exe
*.pyd
*.pyc
```

`.hg/hgrc`  -- defaults and configuration values for mercurial.
Example:

```
[ui]
verbose = True
username = Joe User <j.user@example.com>
[extensions]
hgext.churn = /home/user/hg/hg/contrib/churn.py
[hgk]
path = /home/user/hg/hg/contrib/hgk
```

`.hgsub` -- locations of all subrepositories and where subrepository checkouts came from.
Example:

```
subrepo1 = https://user@example.org/user/repo
subrepo2 = https://user@example.org/user2/repo2
```

`.hgtags` -- contains changeset hash values and text tag names
Example(same format as localtags):

```
8a7b128ab80b58fc2e63258c9e2bf1f58a5be7c2 myfirsttag
08ff3a0b2e5af9a74becbfdf3e92d6e9a2d0c960 secondtag
6535d105ea795a38808481b160314f9857736c53 thirdtag
```

Comment: `.hg\hgrc` is the per-repo config file, right?  There is also a per-user config, on Windows mine is located at `C:\Users\username\mercurial.ini` but I assume there is something similar on Linux/Unix. This is probably worth mentioning to avoid confusion... In fact, you could even just broaden the scope of the Q a little to include that. Also FWIW TortoiseHG makes both available from the same settings screen, so I think people will mostly need to know about both & how they interact.